# cv2 insert transparent image

Tags: numpy, opencv

I have code:

```
while self.cap.isOpened():
    i += 1
    length = int(self.cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    pbar.setValue(( i / length) * 100)
    ret, frame = self.cap.read()
    height = int( frame.shape[0] )
    width = int( frame.shape[1] )

    dim = (width, height)

    frame = cv.resize(frame, dim, interpolation = cv.INTER_AREA)
    org_frame = frame

    if not ret:
        continue

    aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_6X6_250)
    parameters = aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
    corners, ids, _ = aruco.detectMarkers(frame, aruco_dict, parameters=parameters)

    if np.all(ids != None):
        for c in corners :
            x1 = (c[0][0][0], c[0][0][1]) 
            x2 = (c[0][1][0], c[0][1][1]) 
            x3 = (c[0][2][0], c[0][2][1]) 
            x4 = (c[0][3][0], c[0][3][1])   
            im_dst = frame
            size = self.img_src.shape
            pts_dst = np.array([x1, x2, x3, x4])
            pts_src = np.array(
                           [
                            [0,0],
                            [size[1] - 1, 0],
                            [size[1] - 1, size[0] -1],
                            [0, size[0] - 1 ]
                            ],dtype=float
                           );
            
            h, status = cv.findHomography(pts_src, pts_dst)
            temp = cv.warpPerspective(self.img_src.copy(), h, (org_frame.shape[1], org_frame.shape[0])) 
            cv.fillConvexPoly(org_frame, pts_dst.astype(int), 0, 16);
            #cv.addWeighted(org_frame, 0.7, pts_dst.astype(int), 0.3,16, 0);
            org_frame = cv.add(org_frame, temp)
        self.out.write(org_frame)
        cv.imshow('Test', org_frame)
    else:
        self.out.write(frame)
        cv.imshow('Test', frame)

    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

It looks for a label in the frame and inserts my mask image there.

I'm interested in this line:
`cv.fillConvexPoly(org_frame, pts_dst.astype(int), 0, 16);`

Everything works, but when I insert a transparent image, it is filled with black, how can I add transparency?

Mask:
[image]

P.S

sorry for my English

Comment: show us the picture

Comment: what's all that aruco stuff doing there? if it's not relevant, remove it. please review [mre].